# Running Selenium in docker container

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

Console Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2CAN.png

I'm trying to run a python scrip using selenium in a docker container. There hasn't been any issues running other scripts using selenium, so I know it's not an issue with the chromedriver path. When I run the script locally, it works just fine. But when I run in the container, I get the error below. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Code:

```
from datetime import date 
from datetime import timedelta 
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy import Request
from cryptospiders.items import AssetsSRScrape
import requests, json, time, scrapy, itertools, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

timestamp = datetime.now()
dates = datetime.now().date()
allowed_domains = ["stakingrewards.com"]

chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36')

options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

class assetsSRScrape(Spider):
    
    name = 'assetssrscrape'
    item = AssetsSRScrape()
    
    def start_requests(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=options)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        yield SeleniumRequest(url = "https://www.stakingrewards.com/cryptoassets", wait_time=10, callback = self.parse)
   
    def parse(self, response):

        self.driver.get(response.url)

        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ReactTable").get_attribute("outerHTML"), 'html.parser')

        rows = soup.findAll('div', {"class": 'rt-tr-group'})
            
        for row in rows:
           print(str(row.findAll('div', {"class": 'rt-td'})[1].findAll('span')[0].text).strip())
                
        self.driver.quit();
```

DockerFile:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && pip install --upgrade setuptools 
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnotify-dev \
    libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 \
    libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb \
    libgbm-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY . .

RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | \
    tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
    wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | \
    apt-key add - && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable libxss1

RUN BROWSER_MAJOR=$(google-chrome --version | sed 's/Google Chrome \([0-9]*\).*/\1/g') && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_${BROWSER_MAJOR} -O chrome_version && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`cat chrome_version`/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/ && \
    DRIVER_MAJOR=$(chromedriver --version | sed 's/ChromeDriver \([0-9]*\).*/\1/g') && \
    echo "chrome version: $BROWSER_MAJOR" && \
    echo "chromedriver version: $DRIVER_MAJOR"

# Add scrapy as a user
RUN groupadd -r scrapy && useradd -r -g scrapy -G audio,video scrapy \
    && mkdir -p /home/scrapy && chown -R scrapy:scrapy /home/scrapy

# Run Chrome non-privileged
USER scrapy
```

Output

```
  File "/cryptospiders/spiders/stakingrewards.py", line 53, in parse
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ReactTable").get_attribute("outerHTML"), 'html.parser')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ReactTable"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=93.0.4577.63)

2021-09-02 15:53:02 [cryptospiders.rotating_proxies_custom.middlewares] DEBUG: 6 proxies moved from 'dead' to 'reanimated'
```

Comment: Please add your docker file also.

Comment: Just added a link @demouser123

Comment: Please post it as text, screenshots of code and stack traces can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I added it at the bottom of the code snippet @KlausD.

Comment: And now the error output as well...

Comment: is that easier to see now? @KlausD.